# Prove that if $K$ is polynomially convex, then $\mathbb{C}-K$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, maximum-principle

> Prove that if $K$ is polynomially convex, then $\mathbb{C}-K$ is connected.

My Try:

Suppose $K$ is polynomially convex. Then $K=\hat{K}$. So, given $z\in \mathbb{C}-K$, there is a polynomial $p(z)$ such that $|p(z)|>max_{\zeta\in K}|p(\zeta)|$. If we assume that $\mathbb{C}-K$ is not connected, then it has at least 2 components. After that, I was stuck. Can somebody please help me to proceed?

Comment: What is polynomially convex? Also what does $\hat{K}$ stand for?

Comment: $\hat{K}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |p(z)|\leq max_{\zeta\in K}|p(\zeta)| \text{for all polynomials} \;$p$\}$. $K$ polynomially convex means $K=\hat{K}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ is compact then it is contained in $\{ |z| \le R \} $ for some $R > 0$.
The component of $\mathbb{C}-K$ containing $\{ |z| > R \}$ is the "unbounded component".
All other components of $\mathbb{C}-K$ are contained in $\{ |z| \le R \} $and therefore bounded.

Assume that  $\mathbb{C}-K$  has a bounded component
$D$. Any polynomial $p$ is holomorphic in $D$ and continuous on
$\overline D$. It follows from the *maximum modulus principle* that
for all $z \in D$,
$$
|p(z)| \le \max_{\zeta\in \partial D}|p(\zeta)| \le \max_{\zeta\in  K}|p(\zeta)| 
$$
since $\partial D \subset K$ and therefore $z \in \hat K$.
This shows:

> If $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ is compact then any bounded component of $\mathbb{C}-K$ is contained in $\hat K$.

In particular, if $K$ is polynomially convex ($\hat K = K$)
then $\mathbb{C}-K$ cannot have a bounded component, so that
$\mathbb{C}-K$ is simply-connected.