# If $K$ is polynomially convex, show that the components of the interior of $K$ are simply connected.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

> If $K$ is polynomially convex, show that the components of the interior of $K$ are simply connected.

$K$ is called polynomially convex if $K=\hat{K}$, where $\hat{K}=\{w \in \mathbb{C}: |p(w)| \leq \max\{|p(z)|:z \in K\}\}$ for all polynomials $p(z)$.

Since interior of $K$ is open, I know any (bounded) component of interior of $K$ is open and thus I think I am supposed to use following criterion: An open connected set $G$ is simply connected $\iff$ $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}-G$ is connected.

How do I show that for the above component $D$, $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}-D$ is connected?

Any hints will be appreaciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1518289/42969